# sql logical compression of records

Tags: sql, algorithm, compression

I have a table in SQL with more than 1 million records which I want to compress using following algorithm  ,and now I'm looking for the best way to do that ,preferably without using a cursor .

if the table contains all 10 possible last digits(from 0 to 9) for a number (like 252637 in following example) we will find the most used Source (in our example 'A') and then remove all digits where Source = 'A' and insert the collapsed digit instead of that (here 252637) .
the example below would help for better understanding.

### Original table :

```
Digit(bigint)| Source
             | 
2526370      | A
2526371      | A
2526372      | A
2526373      | B
2526374      | C
2526375      | A
2526376      | B
2526377      | A
2526378      | B
2526379      | B
```

### Compressed result :

```
252637       |A
2526373      |B
2526374      |C
2526376      |B
2526378      |B
2526379      |B
```

Comment: This sounds a bit weird, perhaps you could provide some more information about the problem you are trying to solve? Then we might be better able to answer your question. Perhaps post a table structure, along with some sample data and examples of the kinds of queries that you want to perform.

Comment: Why not simply convert the number to a higher base instead of using this compression algorithm? You can represent a pretty large number in just a few characters if you use A-Z.  Z = 2^26.

Comment: @Xcaliburp : there is a sample table and result and also I've explained the algorithm ,so if there is anything special that you couldn't understand let me know and I will try to explain more .

Comment: @Tim : please look at the example that is there I need the result to look like what we have there

Comment: What does "look like" mean?  I was suggesting a way to represent a large number in much fewer characters. Isn't that the main issue?

Comment: As Xcaliburp said, you have not really described the real-world problem you're trying to solve very clearly.  Are you trying to compress your data? Something else?

Comment: @Tim - I may be mistaken, but I think he wants to reduce the number of rows rather than the storage space - i.e faster queries. Even so, changing base won't help, a 64-bit binary number can hold 18446744073709551616 discrete values regardless of the base. The base would matter if he was using a string value - but that is because a char is 1 byte, and only 10 discrete values are used in base10.

Comment: @X: But he could use a string value (if we were trying to reduce the number of bytes). Eliminating rows is too arcane for me to think about.

Comment: @Asha - We can see the table and data you've given us. It's not clear to me if you want to reduce storage (less bytes to represent the same data), or if your queries are slow so you want fewer rows. If you could tell us that, then my gut feeling is that there is a better solution all round.

Comment: @Xcaliburp-no my problem is not storage , I just want to reduce the number of records as shown (10 to 6 in example) , and I have to do it in the explained way because other applications are looking at this table .so what I'm looking for is to implement the algorithm in SQL. thanks

Comment: @Tim - He's using an 8-byte binary column thats 8 bytes where each byte can contain 256 different values - that's a big base. If he switched to a character column, he might use ASCII-85, where he would get 85 different values per byte. There's no way that will save him space - unless he doesn't actually need a bigint. But he could always use an int... :-)

Comment: @Asha - How do your applications know the difference between 252637|A (the only value with Source A) and 252637|A (the compression of 6 values with Source A) or is that irrelevant?

Comment: @Xcaliburp - the purpose here is just reducing the number of records as I have explained , but anyway there is a function which would get a digit and return the related source which can work with the compressed result .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could identify the rows which are candidates for compression without a cursor (I think) by GROUPing by a substring of the Digit (the length -1) HAVING count = 10. That would identify digits with 10 child rows. You could use this list to insert to a new table, then use it again to delete from the original table. What would be left would be rows that don't have all 10, which you'd also want to insert to the new table (or copy the new data back to the original).

Does that makes sense? I can write it out a bit better if it doesn't.

Possible SQL Solution:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(t.Digit,0,len(t.Digit)-1)

    (SELECT TOP 1 Source
        FROM innerTable i
        WHERE SUBSTRING(i.Digit,0,len(i.Digit)-1)
                = SUBSTRING(t.Digit,0,len(t.Digit)-1)
        GROUP BY i.Source
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    )

FROM table t
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(t.Digit,0,len(t.Digit)-1)
HAVING COUNT(*) = 10
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Tom but what about the Source because we have to find the most frequent source for each group of digits. look at the example .

Comment: Oh yeah! Well, you could use a sub-select, something along the lines of SELECT top 1 Source From theTable WHERE SUBSTRING(Digit,0,len-1) = fieldname_from_the_parent_statement GROUP BY Source ORDER BY Count(Digit) DESC.  That would (I think) return the most used Source? It's not very pretty, but it's probably still faster than a cursor.

Comment: You could build that subselect into the original insert.

Comment: @Tom - I can see how the both queries would separately work for returning Digits having all 10 possible last digits and also the most used source but can't link these two together for deleting and inserting the most used , if you can write a pseudo-code or sql code that would help a lot . thanks

Comment: i've edited the original answer in order to make use of the syntax layout and highlighting.

Comment: you can use LEFT(t.Digit,len(t.Digit)-1) instead of substring , the code is working however I'm trying to improve the performance but anyway thanks for the response

Comment: Rather than SUBSTRING or LEFT, you could just divide by 10. It might perform better since you are already using an integer (bigint) type.

Answer (score 2):

This is just another version of [Tom Morgan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257451/sql-logical-compression-of-records/5258626#5258626) accepted answer. It uses division instead of substring to trim the least significant digit off the BIGINT digit column:

```
SELECT     
    t.Digit/10      
    (
        -- Foreach t, get the Source character that is most abundant (statistical mode).
        SELECT TOP 1 
            Source         
        FROM 
            table i         
        WHERE 
            (i.Digit/10) = (t.Digit/10)         
        GROUP BY 
            i.Source         
        ORDER BY 
            COUNT(*) DESC     
    )  
FROM 
    table t     
GROUP BY 
    t.Digit/10  
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 10
```

I think it'll be faster, but you should test it and see.

Comment: ah nice. Yes you're right, theory says it should be faster. (In theory, there's no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is!) +1 for a more performant solution.